# What is wrong in following syntax: Its not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect, jqgrid

I am trying to navigate to another page using the following syntax:

```
                    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        alert("I am raised because of click event");
        window.location = "../Home/Index";
        alert("I am exiting click event");
    });
```

Its entering into the click event handler. Its firing both the alert messages. But, the page is refershing intead of redirecting to another page.(index view)

Is there any alternatitve way of doing this? I am using aspx View engine.

Comment: Why not use a normal <a href="">Link</a> tag and have a class on it that makes it look like a button? If that really is all you are doing?

Comment: What about ` window.location = "/Home/Index";`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button probably also cause a ASP.NET postback, which makes the page reload.

return false from your click handler to prevent this.

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {
    alert("I am raised because of click event");
    window.location = "../Home/Index";
    alert("I am exiting click event");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Mikeal The Problem was that i used type="submit" instead of type="button". Anyways Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net's button control `<asp:button>` will cause page to postback. So you could do 2 things:

1) As Mikael said you could return false in your click handler, 
2) Or you could use an html input control for your button to prevent the postback. (`<input type="button" />`) unless you have other requirements to use asp:button.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
window.location.href="your path";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, this will not solve the problem. `window.location` is settable as it is.

Comment: In this case "window.location" is the same as "window.location.href". This won't solve the problem.